# Attribute Error: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'iterlists'

Tags: python, django

```
 context = {
        'form': form,
        'adv_form': adv_form,
        'shown': shown,
        'models': models_filter,
        'types': types_filter,
        'devices': dev_dict,
        'username': request.user.username,
        'request': dict(request.GET.iterlists()),
        'page': page_results,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'page_range': page_range,
        'query': query,
        'status':status,
        'suggestion': None,
        'myartifacts': myartifacts,
    }
```

I am getting that crash, once I moved my application from python 2.7 to python 3.6. ('request': dict(request.GET.iterlists()))
Can anyone help me with solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iterlists()` was undocumented function for QueryDict build on Py2. Use `dict(request.GET.lists())` instead.

Read short description [here](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.iterlists)

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 -> 3 convention is to rename all `iterX` methods to `X`, so change `dict(request.GET.iterlists())` to `dict(request.GET.lists())`

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the documentation that iterlists() is only available for Python 2

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.iterlists

My assumptions is that you would probably use lists() in its place for Python 3

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.iterlists

Hope that helps